# Call a function inside an if statement bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

I have these code in bash, but i need to call the functions inside the if statement but it doesn't work any ideas?

```
v="1"
if [ "$v" != "1" ]; then
        yes
else
        no
fi


yes(){
        echo "the value is "$v""
}
no(){
        echo ""$v" same value"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement is fine; you simply need to define the functions before you attempt to call them.

```
yes(){
        echo "the value is $v"
}
no(){
        echo "$v same value"
}

v="1"
if [ "$v" != "1" ]; then
        yes
else
        no
fi
```

(`bash`, being dynamically scoped, will use whatever variable `v` is in scope at the time it is called.)